# heima588.com looks exactly the same as Stack Overflow, what is the link between them?

Tags: support

Recently, while searching for some technical stuff using Google, a peculiar link came up with the other search results. I tried to visit the site, but it looks like an exact clone of http://stackoverflow.com

What is that? What is the link between SO and http://heima588.com?

Comment: No link other than that that site is violating the copyright and trademark of Stack Overflow.

Comment: The site is also badly broken.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is an exact copy, So what would be the next course of action from our side.

Comment: Report the site to the team: [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Reported the details to the team. :)

Comment: It would be ironic if they had a meta.heima588.com too :)

Comment: I'm following a more direct path than usual in making sure someone at the executive level sees this. Holy pixel-by-pixel copies, Batman!

Comment: @SufiDeveloper: did you actually try it? (warning: NSFW content) :p

Comment: *"Imitation is the sincerest of flattery"* - Charles Caleb Colton. Though, I wonder if he would feel the same way about cloning.

Comment: It's down now: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/heima588.com

Comment: @ComFreek Only the homepage is. Add `/questions/` and … oh now it's also down. Via Google, most cloned questions have a PHP warning about full disk on VPS. SO won by KO :)

Comment: Why did it get down?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Hahaha tried it now and it looks very original :D

Comment: oh and btw, you were just infected with malware. lol... err well hopefully not.

Comment: Is there any danger that logging into that site might make passwords/credentials available to those running the site?

Comment: @ComFreek Try the link in Bretsky's answer - it still works for me

Comment: @gordonlinoff I think there is a real risk that passwords would be compromised yes.

Comment: I don't know if anyone wants to really log into it. Gross!!!

Comment: ...aaaaaaand the site is down

Comment: maybe we can redirect help vampires to that site

Comment: Even better would be to redirect the close/deletion warriors there, but sadly I think it lacks a meta, so they'd get bored quickly...

Comment: By the way, this heima site now appears to be a chinese shopping site.

Comment: This is now an online casino (gambling website).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There is no link between Stack Overflow and that site, other than that, the site does a bad job of copying all of Stack Overflow.

The site is violating Stack Exchange copyright and trademark by copying the design, logo and the contents, see the footer where it says:

> site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc

Various parts of the site are badly broken too.

Feel free to report the site to the Stack Exchange, using the [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers).

Comment: I still don't understand something ... how do they exact copy the entire site. is it kind a saved/cached pages? bit confused.

Comment: @Rahul: in this case they are copying the HTML, leaving intact the stylesheets and image references. As a result, your browser styles the HTML exactly the same way Stack Overflow is styled.

Comment: LOL .. then they have put enough effort to do this sort of smuggling :). BTW, the site is total down now.

Comment: A link from the SO homepage to this question sends enough traffic to bring the site down. :)

Answer (score 123):

This doesn't appear to be a scraper, but a ***proxy*** of some kind, which appears to run about 10 minutes behind the main site. As it appears that the site is hosted somewhere in China, this *could* be a way someone has devised in order to make Stack Overflow accessible. I don't know - we're looking into it some more.

***I would not attempt to log into that site to poke and explore it***, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Me neither. I don't trust these hacky-wacky sites. Might be full of trojans/malwares.

Comment: The *sign up* and *log in* links in the top bar are linking to `https://stackoverflow.com/`, perhaps because the proxy replaces all instances of `http://stackoverflow.com` but not https links.

Comment: If the proxy runs 10 minutes behind then it is *still a scraper* as it must have scraped a copy 10 minutes earlier to store it. :-P I know, pendantry will not get me anywhere..

Comment: @MartijnPieters There's a line between caching (as a typical squid proxy does) and _scraping_ (saving a copy _as_ a copy, not something that expires).

Comment: Sure, I am not being serious here. Glad this is taken seriously, btw.

Comment: Ah, America and China, the extreme opposite ends of the Copyright spectrum.

Comment: @TimPost You say "a way to make Stack Overflow accessible", do you mean that the real SO is normally blocked in China?

Comment: What's that you say? 10 minutes *in the past*? A new frontier of time-travel-enabled fastest-gun-in-the-west lies before us.

Comment: @MrLister SO in China was having problems with the JavaScript in the recent past due to the Google blockage (but was still semi-usable), but everything has been a-ok for a while now.

Comment: If this is truly something nefarious and/or commercial AND is being hosted in the PRC then you could report them to the relevant authorities (can't tell you who exactly). Sites hosted in China must be registered and display their corresponding ICP number at the bottom of the homepage. E.g. see Baidu for an example: ICP证030173号. Since they don't have this they can potentially be shut down. And if they did have this then you could track them down...

Comment: Funny, we were just talking about [accessing SO from China](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267715/456814).

Comment: It's not even 10 minutes behind the main site right now, maybe 2-3 minutes max. I had 3 upvotes on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146969/excel-to-mysql-free-tool-needed-urgently 5 minutes ago, now I have 5, and http://heima588.com/questions/25146969/excel-to-mysql-free-tool-needed-urgently reflects this.

Comment: @zyboxinternational It's definitely a proxy - just one that has a hard time keeping up (and well, considering our volume, that's sort of expected). Devs are looking into it.

Comment: @TimPost As I mentioned in my answer, it's probably a low-end VPS that's hosting the site. It would make a LOT of sense in this instance...

Comment: @TimPost http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267976/2518525

Comment: lol I logged in on that site. Now when i accessed it. It just give me white screen.

Answer (score 22):

It is still up by the way. I know this should be a comment and not an answer, but I don't have the necessary reputation to comment.

http://heima588.com/questions/24969251/how-to-display-pdf-file-contents-as-well-as-its-full-name-in-the-browser-using-c

Link. The home page is down, so is /questions, but /answers lets me access the site, most of which redirects to the legitimate stackoverflow.com

Comment: I must say, leaving a comment as an answer on MSO is so ironic I almost have to upvote it. I won't bother with the semi-rant that tells you to be patient until you have enough rep to comment...so, I suppose I will...

Comment: I figured it was important to tell people that the website is still up.

Comment: No it's not. From yesterday night I tried almost 10 times and can't access. I think that site is not accessible from India.

Comment: It is accessible as of right now, in Canada, but only some parts of it work.

Comment: It's also not only still accessible from that link in the US, but the homepage works for me as well

Comment: Why is it important to frequently report if another site is up or down on MSO?

Comment: This proxy site obviously has limited bandwidth and since this thread was posted, it's been going down quite frequently.

Comment: @martin-capodici Because the site is a complete copy of SE.

Comment: @Bretsky It's not an *exact copy*, it's a proxy that seems to be caching each page once every 10 minutes-or-so. I'm timing how often it updates (by picking up a comment I made on a question). Once done, I'll post an answer to this..

Comment: There. You now have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 14):

I personally find this sad. It could be a legitimate reason like the host country has blocked Stack Overflow and this site is acting as a proxy, but I've done some digging.

When running a ping on this site:

```
ping heima588.com
```

The returned IP is: `103.6.84.70`

#### Reverse IP

A reverse IP lookup on heima588.com warrants the following domains ([<sup>*Source*</sup>](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/))

```
32ie.com            www.byby-sh5.com
heima588.com        www.diandaomedia.com
longhack.com        www.heima588.com
www.bjxdqcyp.com    www.tumourhealth.com
```

None of the domains hosted on the same IP above seem to bear any resemblance to the trouble domain (heima588.com). So I ruled them out of the equation for now.

The originating IP address resolves to Honk Kong, China. ([<sup>*Source*</sup>](http://www.infosniper.net/index.php?ip_address=103.6.84.70&map_source=1&overview_map=1&lang=1&map_type=1&zoom_level=7))

Doing some more snooping, and looking at the DNS Name servers, it seems that the IP & subsiquently the sites, are hosted through [Mongit](http://www.mongit.com/) / [Host Virtual](http://www.hostvirtual.com) (Host Virtual seems to host VPS installations in Hong Kong, China ([<sup>*Source*</sup>](http://www.hostvirtual.com/datacenters/hong-kong-vps))).

#### ASN Lookup

The ASN lookup warrants the same information, it is owned by **Host Virtual**, or should I say it is hosted by them. ([<sup>*Source #1*</sup>](http://ipinfo.io/AS36236), [<sup>*Source #2*</sup>](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/as/36236))

And looking at the IP Block associated, we see that our returned IP is in fact hosted via Host Virtual through "China Mobile". ([<sup>*Source*</sup>](http://ipinfo.io/AS36236/103.6.84.0/24))

#### Conclusion

I might have found the culprit/guilty party at fault here. I've stumbled upon a person that talks about, and I quote:

> *As Chinese government banned many foreign websites like youtube,*
>   *blogger, facebook and so forth, i feel the crisis of human rights in*
>   *China!*

I'm not going to post/publish the name/information on here, but if a moderator would like to contact me to verify/get this info to see if it is indeed so, please do if you haven't already found out who the party at fault here is. Just trying to help out here.

Comment: Looks like a person with a good motive using the wrong means.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Exactly what I was thinking. This person doesn't seem the slightest bit malicious from what I can find, but you can never judge a book by its cover.

Comment: I don't understand why there would be such a pressing need to provide a proxy for Stack Overflow. News and social media sites, sure, but is access to [so] really such a pressing human rights need?

Comment: @Cupcake Take it the chinese government doesn't want its people to know how to code properly or solve any issues.

Comment: Man!! that's a nice investigation Eh!!

Comment: Because [China breaks HTTPS](http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/360/its-almost-impossible-to-sign-up-at-se-at-china/367#367), @Cupcake. Sad but true.

Answer (score 6):

This is the response to the report filed by me, from the Stack Exchange team,

> Thank you for reporting this content. I've passed the information
>   along to the person at our company who handles such issues. It's the
>   diligence of users like you that helps us stay valuable!
>
> Please note, bringing these sites into compliance (or getting them to
>   no longer serve our content) is often a long and arduous process. You
>   may not see immediate results. However, rest assured that we're
>   working on it.
>
> Thank you again, Stack Exchange Team

So from this we can understand that the target site has been considered under action. and we cannot expect any sudden changes regarding the shutting down process of that site.

Answer (score 4):

I commented on a question, bought up the same question on [heima588.com](http://heima588.com) and waited. The comment hasn't turned up on the site yet, and it's been 25 minutes.

I browsed the site, and quite a few times I got a message that there's no space left on the host, which appears to be a low-end VPS (judging by the error message and abysmal performance of the site):

[image]

It also appears to have hardly any resources available to it since the above error isn't uncommon and sometimes the site ceases to load at all.

As [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) mentioned, it's probably a badly-designed (unauthorised) proxy that somebody has set-up to get around a block in their country or ISP, most likely to do with the issues with StackExchange using Google-hosted JavaScript code when China blocked access to Google.

The domain's DNS is with [DNSPod](http://dnspod.com) which looks similar to [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/).

All in all, it's **not a good idea to go logging into the site, since it could potentially get your username/password**.

Comment: Damn, that's one huge taskbar you have there

Comment: http://hostcabi.net/domain/heima588.com simple data regarding the hosting and http://whois.domaintools.com/heima588.com for the domain info. Site appears to be blank for me now.

Comment: @DJDavid98 It's easier to switch between programs, especially when programming (I usually have many windows open, they go onto at least two rows on the taskbar).