# Is Stack Overflow accessible in China?

Tags: discussion, china

I am aware that the Chinese government blocks certain websites. Are any of the Stack Exchange sites among them?

Comment: Well my friend in China has never mentioned any problems with accessing Stack Overflow.

Comment: Simple check. Go to China, then go to the different Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Oded  <sarcasm> Thanks.  I don't know why I didn't think of that. </sarcasm>  ;)

Comment: @AndreSilva you don't need to be in China to be a frequent user of [chinese.se].

Comment: http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/index.php?siteurl=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F

Comment: [Related post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265298/nation-which-have-most-number-users-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion [also extremely related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267682/456814). Funny, I guess this partially proves me wrong. Or maybe something else entirely is going on that no one really understands yet.

Comment: Chinese users [do access SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103995/245167) and [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191338/245167). Hope they come and share their views here @Cupcake

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I have my doubts that anyone in China would want to speak up about this. Because, you know, that whole political repression and police state thing.

Comment: Related: [heima588.com looks exactly the same as Stack Overflow, what is the link between them?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267676/456814).

Comment: Don't know for today but 8 months back it was not blocked but unusable, they do block google in day time, which means google cdn too which means jquery didn't load. I had to write a user scipt to use a local version of jquery to be able to navigate SO.

Comment: I'm going to China shortly and just had a friend try it, blocked (from Harbin)

Comment: Latest news: The SO servers are pingable, but transfer rates are 1998 dial-up modem speeds.  Is anyone else seeing these issues?

Comment: No need long stories. Answer is Yes.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Stack Overflow is generally accessible in China.

However, it is getting occasionally blocked, thanks to Ciro Santilli, who includes banned keywords in his name.

(Yes, [he answered this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267715/is-stack-overflow-accessible-in-china/288497#288497) too.)

The content below is a more or less verbatim copy of Ciro Santilli's user page. If you dispute about what I said, please at least read and contrast with his user page on Stack Overflow before claiming that "No, he doesn't want to annoy Chinese programmers" or calling me "name calling". Different from the stuff above, I will try to maintain a neutral tone here. But note that my answer isn't supposed to be neutral. I *am* affected by this man's action.

Ciro Santilli's girlfriend was a [Falun Gong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falun_Gong) practitioner and was prosecuted by the Chinese government. Ciro then adds many filtered keywords in China in his Stack Overflow username. His stated goals include "increase the cost of censorship" via making China "lose money with worse IT".

Ciro also included some defense and links to Meta Stack Overflow  about whether including political stuff in user names is fine in Stack Overflow. You are free and recommended to read them.

Comment: You can [flag for a moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213180/reporting-an-inappropriate-or-offensive-user-name/213181#213181) if you find things that are offensive/abusive. No need to call users out.

Comment: Actually, think of it as just trying to degrade the automated chinese censorship. Yes, it's annoying if you hit a block, but you really should blame those who create and maintain that abomination, instead of those who try to counter it, even if they fail or use the wrong methods...

Comment: I do blame the creators (and the masterminds behind them) of the firewall. However, this is a question about "is it accessible?", and I think "it is accessible but banned keywords cause problems" is an informative answer. And, well, Ciro is a spectacular example of why banned keywords cause problems even if we don't talk about politics at all in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yi Yang, you keep editing your post by saying Ciro's intention is to annoy Chinese Programmer.  You are the one who blame the victim, and not blaming the ridiculous system.

Comment: If Ciro lives in China or is a dissident. Then yes, he is a victim of the firewall. But he isn't. And Falun Gong is a different issue from the Firewall.

Comment: @Unreality, check Ciro's userpage on Stackoverflow. He explicitly stated his goal is to "increase the cost of censorship" by making China "lose money with worse IT". That is his intention. The IT companies are not owned by the Chinese government, but are yet his direct targets.

Comment: @Unreality The problem is the ridiculous system is always there and Ciro's action does not look like it will help its demise. And when a "freedom fighter" fights for his own girlfriend's freedom at the expense of other people, sorry, I can't really tell the difference between the said freedom fighter and tyranny itself.

Comment: OK. I added some verbatim quotes from Ciro's user page. Whether Ciro's action is more directed to the Chinese government or the Chinese IT industry (and thus Chinese programmers) is left to the judgement of the reader. Hopefully @Unreality won't object my answer any more.

Comment: The new version is fine. Whether Ciro helps or not depends on the total opposing force against China Gov is big enough or not. Once the opposing force is big enough to an extent, then China Gov has to change and all Chinese Programmers will be beneficial from it. Remember: "All that is necessary for evil to triumph is for good men to do nothing"

Comment: Again, I'd reserve my respect to those who actually fought against the oppression, not those who sit behind and abuse their options at hand to "command" others to fight.

Comment: Programmers have a heart and moral principles. At StackOverflow, we share knowledge with the heart. And defending justice is also part of the heart. Regrettably, State control over the news media in China is achieved through a complex combination of party monitoring of news content, legal restrictions on journalists and financial incentives for self-censorship. The Chinese government bought the hearts of many Chinese. Then the question should be: Is "The Free Thought" accessible in China?

Comment: @derive111 We spend time, energy and money to set up tunnels to view banned stuff. The free thought, or whatever you call it, is indeed accessible to many of us, but not because the openness of the government, but the effort of the many.

Sadly, I feel Ciro's effort does not add to it. Rather, it makes our effort more costly.

Comment: Also, while the freedom of speech and related stuff are as universal as they are, the cause of Falun Gong is controversial at best. Many of us, myself included, do not really support the Falun Gong cause. When this self-claimed religious leader started to claim he was able to cure people among other pseudo-scientific miracles (for a fee, of course), sorry, I do think he should be arrested for this, even if people have different ideas if it's a cult or a religion.

Comment: Falun Gong is irrelevant here. Though restrictions from China Gov is.

Comment: Seems like Ciro Santilli is reaching partly one goal: 'in order to make Chinese programmers either: a) mad and start a revolution ...' Now waiting for the revolution to start.

Comment: @YìYáng, Re "That is his intention"; I think you have completely missed his intention. It was never a retaliation against Chinese people but the **Chinese government**. The intention is to get the word out so that the government would finally acquiesce and **change**. At the rate of 1 mouth spreading to 25k minds, just 1k mouths can spread to 25m minds.

Comment: @YìYáng,  If someone is doing something questionable, you **do not torture** `https://www.google.com/search?q=falun+gong+torture&source=lnms&tbm=isch` them. The moment you do that, you retaliate questionable injustice with something of unquestionable injustice. These Chinese authorities would even pursue people who are overseas: `https://www.google.com/search?q=Falun+Gong+Practitioner+in+South+Africa+Shot`. I don't believe you have access to this information if you are living inside the firewall.

Comment: @Pacerier The word will not spread to Chinese people because they trigger immediate firewall ban. Ciro's only effect would be putting stackoverflow and github out of the firewall, not putting whatever you want into the firewall. And yes, I recommend you to read his own completely unbiased FAQ.

Comment: @YìYáng, Re "the rate of 1 mouth spreading to 25k minds, just 1k mouths can spread to 25m minds"; I'm not referring to the Chinese; I'm talking about minds outside the wall which would get the China government to acquiesce and change by the collective action of the minds.

Comment: interesting fact: As part of the Great Firewall, beginning in 2003 China started the Golden Shield Project , a massive surveillance and censoring system, the hardware for which was provided by mostly U.S. companies, including Cisco Systems...

Comment: The text up to: "However, it is getting occasionally blocked" would be enough to answer the question. The remaining part is not necessary.

Comment: When some of you say "China needs to change" have you really been here? I think the upvotes of this answer says everything.

Comment: @Unreality The fact that you are talking about politics on stack overflow says a lot about your character.

Comment: @rene accountability doesn't come from complaining privately to a group of elitists who only care about their own, that is why censorship is heavily restricted in democratic societies, and also why SO can in no way be seen as democratic, but rather oligarchic.

Answer (score 45):

There are many websites that claim to check that for us:

- https://en.greatfire.org/stackoverflow.com
- http://www.blockedinchina.net/?siteurl=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F
- http://viewdns.info/chinesefirewall/?domain=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com
- http://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.china-test.html

All of the above said that Stack Overflow is up.

Also note that there is an important distinction between HTTP and HTTPS:

- HTTP is not encrypted, so the Chinese government may be able to block only certain pages depending on what they contain.
- HTTPS is encrypted, so they don't know what page you are accessing. So they either block the entire domain, or nothing.

As mentioned [by Domi in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267715/is-stack-overflow-accessible-in-china/288497?noredirect=1#comment894610_288497), TLS 1.3 adds an amazing new feature called Encrypted Client Hello (ECH), previously known as ENSI, which actually also encrypts the domain, and would therefore force the GFW to block IPs instead of domains, which is much more error prone. China has however of course [has already banned this protocol](https://www.zdnet.com/article/china-is-now-blocking-all-encrypted-https-traffic-using-tls-1-3-and-esni/). When I'm elected for congress, I will try to pass a law that forces Western websites to use only TLS 1.3.

It has also been brought to by attention by [the 996.ICU event of 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/996_working_hour_system), that Chinese browsers can of course block specific pages within HTTPS websites, but I haven't found a website that reliably tracks this form of censorship. Here's another [specific example on one of my projects](https://github.com/cirosantilli/china-dictatorship/issues/525).

As mentioned at: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360242/895245 , Stack Overflow appears to depend on assets from sources that are blocked in China, leading to certain aspects of the website being broken:

- Google AJAX Library (which if not available, apparently breaks all AJAX calls)
- Imgur for images

I am/was trying to block Stack Overflow / force the end of censorship with anti-communist messages on my username: https://web.archive.org/web/20150415194412/https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%E5%85%AD%E5%9B%9B%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6-%E6%B3%95%E8%BD%AE%E5%8A%9F?tab=profile however I have not found any evidence that this has had any effect on HTTPS.

A small correction/specification to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320914/895245 I wouldn't say my girlfriend was directly persecuted, besides being forced to practice Falun Gong very discreetly when she was in China. It was mostly my mother in law: she was [put in arbitrary detention for 15 days in 2015](https://cirosantilli.com/china-dictatorship/ciro-santilli-mother-in-law-jail), it seems that the police can do that according to the law very easily to anyone, and in several other episodes they would regularly harass her by e.g. going to her home and taking her computer and never giving it back.

A related remark, I have since learnt that the average Chinese developer doesn't speak good English, and is much more likely to just use Chinese websites like [CSDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Software_Developer_Network), one of the many Stack Overflow auto-translators, or some [Chinese Stack Exchange clone](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-Chinese-version-of-Stackoverflow-com). And the developers who do speak English are likely very much able to use a VPN to work around the GFW. Therefore, from this point of view, blocking Stack Exchange may never be a priority for the CCP.

Related: [Is the Stack Exchange Network blocked in China?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272271/is-the-stack-exchange-network-blocked-in-china)

As of 2023, there appears to be a Js check and clear message on top bar when an external source fails to load:

> requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load

Comment: Though they presumably don't check dependencies...

Comment: @Deduplicator do you mean like CDNs for Js and CSS?

Comment: Yes, as well as imgur, gravatar and the like.

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功, Are you in China? Is the archived versions of websites accessed on web.archive.org / archive.is banned in China?

Comment: Re "HTTPS is encrypted, so they don't know what page you are accessing" and "they either block the entire domain, or nothing"; It's easy to narrow down by the **size** of the content.

Comment: @Pacerier interesting concept. But won't size change constantly as comments and answers are edited?

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功, Take a banned HTTP response that's accessed by this set of server IPs, measure the size of the transaction and write it down. Every morning or **every hour, update the database**. Now whenever we have a request from these IPs of this exact size, we break the connection. If the average HTTP response is 100KB, we have only a 1 in 100k chance of false positive. 100 banned responses from this IP? That's only a 100 in 100k chance of false positive. ¶ I believe the concept has...

Comment: ...long (cf https://goo.gl/vXum6R ) been out of research labs and already deployed in Middle East. Information about China is slower/harder because frankly the West can't be much bothered about the average Chinese citizen and so funding in this area is minimized. There is **more** information leaked than just that actually; for example resources always occurs "in batch" (after this request, this CSS request will follow, this IMG request will follow, etc, etc)

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功, Personally, I verily believe it's already deployed in parts of China; take a look at the number of Chinese surnames on the page https://security.stackexchange.com/a/4418/2379

Comment: @Pacerier sure, everything that is doable, they have already done most likely.

Comment: @Z9. see also: https://github.com/cirosantilli/china-dictatorship/tree/5572ccebda43ec64f3297592c59d014df0db105c#effective

Comment: @Z9.They've used this profile picture ever since I've been here. I think you should evaluate your own bias on this one.

Comment: @Z9. commenting here is useless, consider instead commenting in one of the threads mentioned at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/china-dictatorship/tree/49832eda2f579b3f72be8dbc94cadeb0905b0826#stack-overflow or create a new thread.

Comment: Also, one last comment, why would you want to stop a billion people from getting coding help? I don't see how that will help at all.

Comment: @Z9. https://github.com/cirosantilli/china-dictatorship/tree/49832eda2f579b3f72be8dbc94cadeb0905b0826#why-keyword-attack

Comment: So, you want to make everyone lose. Interesting. Also, this is probably not worth it as coding in China has recently exploded as a trend.

Comment: @Z9. I will not reply further here, to get further replies  from me, please create an issue at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/china-dictatorship/issues

Comment: About the HTTPS thing: Right now (2/2022), SO is still running HTTPS with TLS 1.2. China [has banned](https://www.internetsociety.org/news/statements/2020/internet-society-blocking-tls-1-3-in-china-makes-the-internet-less-secure/) the latest TLS 1.3 and its friend ESNI. If SO upgraded to TLS 1.3, it might not be available in China anymore, or (more likely) is going to offer a TLS 1.2 version instead. The beauty of [ESNI](https://blog.cloudflare.com/esni/) is that it finally encrypts the domain name, meaning that the GFW would need to ban IP addresses instead, which is much more error prone.

Answer (score 32):

As a Chinese mainland citizen, I would like to share my experiences visiting the Stack Exchange Network. Leave a comment whenever you need clarification or think this should be updated.

**Update 1:** As of June 2018, the connectivity has been much better, **provided that** you have correctly overridden the dependency of `ajax.googleapis.com`. Otherwise it still loads like snails and turtles. Web pages are fully functional after successfully loading jQuery.

---

Original answer:

### Connectivity

The connection to SE is fairly slow, no matter how fast your network bandwidth is. This is primarily due to the use of [the Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall). Opening question pages, loading user profiles, submitting answers, etc. are all very slow as well.

### Functionality

Since [Google AJAX Library is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89433/350567) in mainland China, you can't expect these functions to work (*at all*!!):

- Real-time preview of posts
- Top-right dropdown menu for notifications, achievements, reviews.

  Strangely, the sites list still works
- Posts update (the `an edit has been made to this post. click here to reload` banner, or `this post has been deleted and is no longer visible`) and certain notifications like question closed
- New question activity on tag page
- Up/Down voting and commenting (reported by others, though I myself have not encountered these)
- Reviewing (The review items just won't load at all)
- More TBA

Besides, people have reported that logging in (with Stack Exchange OpenID) sometimes gets stuck. Let alone Google and Facebook login.

### Workaround?

Use a **VPN** to circumvent GFW, or if you can stand the slow connection while desiring full functionality, use a proxy for Google AJAX Library. Fortunately the evil party didn't block `sstatic.net`, which is used as CDN for various other assets (Logo, CSS and more). It'd be at least satisfactory despite of the slow speed.

Or see my answer [here](/a/360451/5958455) about using a Chrome extension, Resource Override (not affiliated!).

Proxy this domain or some URLs under it:

```
ajax.googleapis.com
```

Comment: Sounds like it'd be a good step forward if Stack Overflow started hosting the JS libraries on their own sstatic.net CDN?

Comment: @Stijn Sure! Definitely! Having to work aroung the AJAX library is a pain because setting up plugins everywhere is boring and tiring,

Comment: In fact, I personally prefer that a revolution happen and overturn the Communist Party. Not only for SO but also for a bunch of other things, the most important of which is Google, which is the solution to *all* trivial questions.

Comment: @iBug, Re "plugins"; Referring to?

Comment: @iBug, Re "personally prefer that a revolution happen and overturn the Communist Party"; Funny, I'm under the impression that you can't say this out in public or you would be sent for correctional training? (Don't worry, I'm not the Chinese.)

Comment: @Parcerier A Chrome extension (namely Resource Override) is mentioned in the linked answer. That's the kind of browser plugin (extension) that I'm referring to.

Comment: @Parcerier I can assure you that the majority of Chinese citizen have the same thoughts. Then I refuse to respond any more on this topic.

Comment: This describes my experiences exactly.  I do not believe Ciro Santilli has anything to do with the speed issues I experienced.  Also worth noting that China cannot see when people are accessing his personal page due to it being protected by https -- but understood that that is not arguing against the point that others are making.

Comment: You may add "_can't create an account_" in your list of broken functionalities

Comment: There are a lot of dumb websites that have all of these dependencies on google, facebook and so on, not realizing that people block these domains for privacy and other reasons.

Answer (score 19):

I think, Stack Overflow itself is not blocked in China, but the Google related stuff is blocked.
Such as the js scripts from Google CDN used by SO or user authentication provided by google for some user using the Google account.

I suggest China users use a paid VPN, it's cheap and stable. But you should choose the VPN carefully. In my personal experience, a VPN may work with China Telecom(中国电信) and not work with China Mobile(中国移动)

Another tip:
Once those resources from Google CDN is cached in your machine, you can access SO without a VPN, and Google account authentication seems also have a cache mechanism. Actually I am visiting SO without VPN right now :D

Comment: Any idea what has changed since last June 2015? (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302667/6309)

Answer (score 14):

Stack Overflow is a technology website, and technology is, along with math and science, apolitical (for the most part). If the Chinese government is going to block anything, it's going to block sites that are critical of it and the ruling Communist party.

If there are any political Stack Exchange sites, or sites that may discuss social and political issues, then I wouldn't be surprised if those end up on China's block list. China has been known to block news of the [Arab Spring protests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Spring), for example, even though they weren't directly related to China, because they're examples of popular uprisings against an authoritarian government<sup>1</sup>.

Stack Overflow itself, however, should be a non-issue, though by creating this post, maybe the Chinese government will start blocking Meta Stack Overflow(?)...

<sup>1</sup>*I can't actually find any references to China blocking Arab Spring news. Can anyone else provide credible references?*

Comment: `If the Chinese government is going to block anything, it's going to block sites that are critical of it and the ruling Communist party.` It sounds like you're *trying* to get MSO blocked...

Comment: @AstroCB China's loss, not ours `:P` Personally, I'm going to sit pretty here and enjoy my Free F**cking Speech. MURICA! F-YEAH!

Comment: There's an sidelong reference to China blocking news of the Arab Spring protests in this [Bloomberg article](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2012-05-01/leaders-in-beijing-feared-arab-spring-could-infect-china.html) from April, 2012: *The U.S. officials said the Chinese leaders’ concern about popular protests prompted by the Arab Spring...have been compounded by the knowledge that China’s “Great Firewall” on the Internet no longer can block reports of the Middle Eastern uprisings...on social media, blogs, websites, and from Chinese students and business people in the U.S. and elsewhere.*

Comment: Seriously now, if they start blocking political sites on the Stackexchange network, won't that mean they'll block the entire stackexchange.com URI? Including the non-political sites?

Comment: @MrLister I don't know. Can you block a particular sub-domain, while not blocking the others? Or are you trying to say that once they block one sub-domain, they'll choose to block everything else as well (i.e. not a technical limitation)?

Comment: This answer is either correct, or naive.  Time will tell.

Comment: Criminey, I hope China doesn't allow SO.  They've got enough problems without building an entire generation of software engineers better at google-fu than at writing code.

Comment: @user456814, It's all about cost and profit. I believe that within 10 years as the atrocities of China get more and more well-known in the western programmer vocabulary, it would be cheaper for China to block the entire stackexchange than to handpick particles by particles. Obviously this needs to be weighed against the [reduction in the cost of handpicking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302740/632951) due to enhanced technology.

Comment: ¶ Google had tried establishing in China but chose to leave eventually due to censorship. Ciro is doing the right thing: If China wants information embargo, they should be prepared to face a massive braindrain from the east to the west, And as for those western investors who decide to invest in China, they would all leave too, straw-by-straw. China simply can't afford to fight this way, for they are currently third in terms of cyber-warfare skills, behind both US and Russia, The birth of cheap AI may just mark their death if they have nothing else to bring to the brinksmanship table.

Answer (score 9):

It would appear that according to this question: [Cannot login SO from China](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228186/cannot-login-so-from-china)

Stack Exchange is accessible from China.  (Even if this person was having issues)

Comment: I asked the question.  Then found the answer in this thread (but it was not _the_ answer to the thread.)

Comment: `<nitpick>`There are no "threads" on Stack Exchange, because none of the sites are discussion forums. There are only questions, and answers.`</nitpick>`.

Comment: The user had problems accessing, but was because [a submarine cable that went kaput,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228323/213575) nothing to do with the firewall.

Answer (score 7):

#### Update on Aug 17, 2016

Well, a bit of good news. Things changed, and as of now, all the major SO/SE sites are directly accessible again. Even better, that also include `sstatic.net`.

[image: http://stackoverflow.com/]

#### Wish List:

1. jQuery served on sstatic.net, at least for users behind GFW
2. **HTTPS only**

#### Update on July 27, 2016

Starting from this week, most major Stack Exchange sites are effectively blocked in China, possibly all of them.

Most major sites include https://StackExchange.com https://StackOverflow.com, https://SuperUser.com, https://ServerFault.com, and all sites using a sub-domain of stackexchange.com, such as [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Actually they have been half broken for a long time, because the use of [jQuery from Google CDN](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js). Which GFW blocks firmly. This effectively makes them readonly to affected users.

Also `sstatic.net`, Stack Exchange's own CDN site has been blocked quite a while ago. This causes all sites lose their layout, styles etc and makes things much worse.

But things like this, blocking all major sites in the Stack Exchange family never happened before.

#### Maybe too late, but why not HTTPS only?

Stack Exchange sites have lots of technical value, and are mostly politics free. But its use of plain HTTP allows GFW to see all the traffic.

The result of being blocked is possibly due to GFW detected certain unwanted stuff. `github.com` was once blocked, but unblocked because of the boycott from its technical merit. And GitHub is HTTPS only, which makes it more safe from machine based censorship.

Comment: SE is mostly HTTPS now, FYI.

Comment: @ryenus, Re "boycott"; Referring to?

Answer (score 5):

I spend four years and a half of my life in China ([PRC version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China))... long story short: yes, you can with a big "BUT" (no kidding here).

I went back to Europe only until very recently (end of Jun. 2016), so what I'm saying is probably still applicable around that circa.

Accessing Stack Overflow is slow and sloppy but, still, it works.

Back then, I could not even log in to my account since a big part of the JavaScript and CSS are leveraging CDN which when not under the great authorization of the GFW... are not loaded, so you're ending up being pretty much doomed).

So yes it works for searching answers (and making the process really slow), but posting stuff of your own might be tricky without having a reliable and almighty VPN.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2018: broken.

All websites in the Stack Exchange network pull JavaScript files from Google (and Facebook too, I believe), both blocked in China. Failure of those scripts results in broken pages. Search works, on occasions. Login is impossible without using a VPN.

More: for instance, this is my fourth attempt to post this message - Stack Overflow requested a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) check to prove I am human. However CAPTCHA is also blocked here behind the great firewall.

Comment: I think I can prove you wrong: I'm active daily on Stack Overflow from Shanghai (same as you) without issues, except for data.stackexchange.com: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305771/how-to-login-normally-to-data-stackexchange-com.

Comment: Note that I have the privilege of [reduced-ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) (requires 200 Reputation), and that may be helping to avoid issues with some scripts.