# Failure of JS and losing site core functions when CDN is unavailable

Tags: support, feature-request

Many of the site's features fail in areas where CDN's are not available. In those cases, the site (which does detect the problem) displays an error alert bar. I believe that This problems can be easily solved with a simple fall-back mechanism to another CDN. (Quick background:  *[Is 'Google Web Fonts' or CDN bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943588/is-google-web-fonts-or-cdn-bad/19969239#19969239)* and *[Is Google’s CDN for jQuery available in China?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607425/is-google-s-cdn-for-jquery-available-in-china/22060903#22060903)*).

While waiting for a delayed flight at a remote airport lounge, I took the opportunity to learn a bit of JS and write an extension to solve this problem.

The result of those 3 hours work is a [Chrome browser extension available](https://bitbucket.org/obmerk99/se-so-cdn-chrome-extention).
Essentially it bypasses CDN by targeting specific requests and redirecting.

I just hope it can help others.

*Small Disclaimer*: This is the first extension I ever wrote , and my JS skills are basically `NULL`. If anyone want to help testing it, improve it, criticize or downvote - be my guest.

Comment: Related: [Add a fallback for jQuery in case it fails to load from Google's CDN](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133786/add-a-fallback-for-jquery-in-case-it-fails-to-load-from-googles-cdn), [Employer blocks jQuery from Google, DOH!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/employer-blocks-jquery-from-google-doh), [Why doesn't Stackoverflow use a jquery fallback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138564/why-doesnt-stackoverflow-use-a-jquery-fallback) and others on MSE.

Comment: Also related: [What else do I need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100)

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Thanks for the comment. 1st-I included the examples in order for people that DO have access to all the cdn´s to be able to visually see the problems. 2nd-I already wrote in the original question that I am sorry for it´s length.3rd-Downvoting this question will not make the problem go away (nor is that an answer).If your proposed answer is the likes of "if you do not have access to our chosen CDN´s like we already wrote in the requirements than go away, do not use the site ,and please do not bother us with petty requests" so please write it as an answer.I might just accept it .

Comment: @MartijnPieters . Another point regarding your comment - I also wrote in the original question that I understand the costs ( did you read the question or just auto-vote ? ) but what I suggested was a fallback. that means that the extra files will not be served to ALL users , but only those who do not have CDN available. I assume that is a bit less than "millions". Also, the difference between serving the `jQuery.min` and the alert bar which the system already serve would be ridiculously low .

Comment: The difference is not ridiculously low when you consider the amount of traffic that Stack Overflow gets. It's like how Google gets a significant bang for their buck when they eliminate 10 characters from their CSS. And yeah, I agree with Martijn here. I tend to be verbose myself, but you could seriously make this point just as effectively (or more so) in a much shorter post. Make the images external links if you really think they need to be there for illustration—people who can't imagine can click on them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - No problem. It is not a personal thing against you. _really_ . I just tried to demonstrate. Deleted now. Please see update . ( I hope you will not find it "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" like you did before...)

Comment: @CodyGray - I never said a fall-back means to serve from own-server. In fact , I proposed other CDNs as fallback ( there is also a Microsoft CDN for jQuery ... ) , and also this - just in cases the first one fails. About the question being too long . I can not apologize more . Please see update.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen: I edited a little more to focus on your content.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Ok. You might want to add those related :  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267715/1244126, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258288/1244126, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269000/1244126 or at least point them to the possible solution described in this question

Comment: @ObmerkKronen: why not add them yourself? Add a 'related posts' section perhaps.