# What's up with China?

Tags: discussion, statistics, china

The number of uniques for China seems to have increased 5 fold or more this last few weeks.
Has anything changed regarding the accessibility of stackoverflow.com in China **starting Friday, June 26th 2015**?

[image: China uniques]

<sup>(image from [`www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com`](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com), views by Top Countries)</sup>

Those numbers used to be 30K-50K the week-end, 70-90K during the week.
Starting June 26th, those numbers more than doubled or tripled (up to a record high of 790K last July 28th).
This last Saturday (August, 15th), there were 580K(!) unique visits from China, around 10 times the usual participation.

That is great, but also puzzling.
Any idea why this increase just took place over the past two months?
What happened last Friday, June 26th?

**I am not talking about a traffic *transfer***
(like a VPN is no longer needed, and some "Rest of World" IP addresses are now being recorded as China IP addresses)
**I am talking about a traffic *increase***;
Stack Overflow has been around for almost 8 years:
**Why the 2 to 5X *increase* starting June 25th, 2015?**
**Why do we see a peak in global visits in the middle of August?** (which always has been the lowest month the previous 7 years)

---

It turns out this seems valid for all or most of the Stack Exchange network.

China traffic for 2014-2015 for the main three sites (SO, SU, and SE):

- [Stack Overflow](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?country=CN):
  [image: SO]
- [Super User](https://www.quantcast.com/superuser.com?country=CN):
  [image: SU]
- [Server Fault](https://www.quantcast.com/serverfault.com?country=CN):
  [image: SF]

Comment: Related to the nuclear-like bomb explosion in Tianjin port city ?

Comment: @CyrilDD hopefully not. That trend started a few weeks before anyway.

Comment: Could be related to the increase of Chinese spam we have seen across the network.

Comment: @Oded but why now? Was stack Overflow not accessible (or less accessible) before the end of June?

Comment: Maybe [that guy's crusade against the Chinese government](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298950/are-political-profiles-that-could-possibly-affect-the-participations-of-other-us) worked after all...

Comment: Is it possible that China expanded their pool of outbound IPs? Are other sites seeing surges too?

Comment: @SteveTauber no, no significant changes (https://www.quantcast.com/serverfault.com, https://www.quantcast.com/superuser.com, https://www.quantcast.com/math.stackexchange.com: pretty stable there, or not even visible)

Comment: @VonC There is growth there too; you can see it on the graph of uniques from China: https://www.quantcast.com/superuser.com?country=CN etc

Comment: @NormalHuman I agree, but not quite in the same proportion as the growth seen in Stack Overflow. It does mimic Stack Overflow growth though.

Comment: Man, seriously, what ***is*** up with China?!

Comment: Looking into this. I suspect our CDN was finally whitelisted, but that's kinda hard to confirm. I'll report back if and when I figure it out.

Comment: @TimPost Thank you. http://www1.cnnic.cn/ and the MIIT are, I presume, the official starting points.

Comment: @TimPost http://http://www.chinainternetwatch.com/1086 is an interesting read. http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/index.php?siteurl=stackoverflow.com seems to show that stackoverflow is indeed visible.

Comment: Am I mistaken, or is the increase also happening for chinese.stackexchange.com ? https://www.quantcast.com/chinese.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TimPost I am a user in mainland China and I can help confirm whether or not something is blocked. Right now the jQuery script from `ajax.googleapis.com` is being blocked (which is a big pain if you try to use SO without a VPN) and the images from `gravatar.com` are being blocked. I don't see anything else being blocked.

Comment: @PeterOlson so you would still need a VPN to use Stack Overflow. Yet, the increase of China IP visits started at the end of June. What changed then?

Comment: @VonC I have no idea, I've been using Stack Overflow while in China since May and I haven't noticed any differences

Comment: @PeterOlson OK. Yet https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?country=CN or https://www.quantcast.com/superuser.com?country=CN or any other Stack Exchange site show a very different traffic before and after June 25th.

Comment: @VonC Yes, I already saw that in the question and comments; I never denied that there's a difference in traffic, whatever the cause may be. All I'm saying is that the increase in traffic is not due to a script being unblocked.

Comment: @TimPost, Does Stack Exchange really use a CDN for jQuery without a fallback to a local jQuery file? That's sound like a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps at all, but, out of curiosity, I'm accessing this page right now with my VPN set to route through a Hong-Kong IP.

Comment: @BoltClock these are all the moments where I have been featured somewhere to my knowledge, mostly related to activism: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/wiki/Publicity-events Let me know if you find any other one.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy Hong Kong (and I think Macau) sort of has its own government separate from the rest of China, so the Great Firewall of China doesn't have effect in Hong Kong.

Comment: Could this have to do with changes to algorithms in search engines over there? Maybe Baidu or Google is driving more traffic than before...

Comment: Chila has more programmers and all of them just came to know about Stackoverflow. What is the problem then ?

Comment: Yeah and the question is *what* exactly led to that.

Comment: Let's call Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: Anything to do with recent supposed chinese cyber attacks? Or maybe someone controlling a legion of zombies bots around the world to web-crawl?

Answer (score 31):

It is really hard to gain access to specific court documents in China. From the looks of it, on July 1st, 2015 a large amount of legislation was not only passed but implemented which altered the way that the "Great Firewall" works. That document can be read in full here: http://chinalawtranslate.com/cybersecuritydraft/?lang=en

It was directly targeting VPN's and apparently was successful this round. [Two major companies in China commented on the change including Astrill and Golden Frog saying that services were affected and that the implementation was very sophisticated **<sup>USA Today</sup>](http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/2015/01/23/china-internet-vpn-google-facebook-twitter/22235707/)**.

While the majority of the implementation deals with restricting content, it also claims to allow an easier route towards loosening restrictions on certain areas of the internet which were not immediate threats to their national security or which contribute to science and education.

This may not be the reason, but it seemed to me to be a factor. Perhaps from one of two angles. First, it may be possible this legislation did relax avenues of access for Stack Overflow in China in some regards. Second, if the VPN's were truly impacted, it is possible that users directly accessing Stack Overflow from China are now actually show up as being from China and not as being from some other proxy.

The above is all conjecture.

What follows is hard fact.

If there were to be a large increase in traffic there should be an increase in new users. However, this does not seem to be the case. There are several graphs already created showing the amount of users created by date. They come from this meta post: [How many new users does Stack Overflow get per day?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252043/how-many-new-users-does-stack-overflow-get-per-day/252054#252054) . Here they are:

[*new accounts per day moving average*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/269343/new-accounts-per-day-moving-average?MovingAvg=20#graph)

[image]

[*new accounts per day raw*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185609/number-of-created-accounts-per-day#graph)

[image]

To me this is a clear indication that there is not an influx of new users at an increased rate. There does seem to be a steady increase in new users, but that seems to be in line with the expectations of the site.

Let's check out voting!
I adapted a query for votes per day here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/352984/number-of-votes-per-day#graph

[image]

As indicated by VonC there does seem to be an increase in voting activity. While each year does show a pattern of having voting per day increase at the start of the year, nothing is as prevalent as the jump shown. However, this jump in voting seems to take place far earlier in the year, late February, and while that is an interesting aspect to look at, it doesn't seem related to an increase in traffic from China nearly half a year later.

Comment: I can confirm on this factor. Some popular free/paid VPNs became (nearly) unusable in the past several months.

Comment: Please see my last edit (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/302667/revisions) about traffic *transfer* vs. traffic *increase*.

Comment: @VonC - When you have an entire location all filtering through one IP address that suddenly moves to multiple addresses, that will show as an increase in traffic. Many places, including educational institutions, were having multiple users affected as the result of the actions from one user because they all had the same IP address. So changing the path of access *will* result in a traffic *increase*.

Comment: @TravisJ I don't buy that one bit. I see an increase of *activity* on the site, more upvotes. This isn't about IPs or VPNs. What happened at the end of June?

Comment: @VonC - Where is your correlation of voting activity in the data you show? All I see is a broad analysis of traffic from third party in your post.

Comment: @TravisJ I was referring of what I see on the site, as a users, independently of the traffic analysis of the question. It "feels" to me there are a lot more people, not just more IPs.

Comment: @VonC - Well, I am definitely not going to argue that you aren't an integral part of the user base here with strong insights. But I also have trouble seeing any indication of increased activity on the site that would correlate to the usage shown in the traffic statistics. It would be nice if there was some data on users created by day that we could see as a graph, or perhaps total votes per day, or questions per day, perhaps over the past 6 months; just to see if this was a change of measurement or an actual change of usage.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree. All I can say is that I have never seen a month of August *that* animated.

Comment: @VonC - I posted some graphs on new user data.

Comment: @VonC - I would say that you are accurate about the voting activity increasing. However, I am not sure that China is the result of the activity and the pattern of voting increase started a lot earlier in the year. Please see the graphs and linked queries for more information.

Comment: @TravisJ Thank you for the data. That's it! The IPs are increasing, but they (China) are all using the same SO account! ;)

Answer (score 17):

Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites are currently accessible directly from China and do not require a VPN - I don't remember clearly if a VPN was necessary earlier.

According to VPNExpress customer service, the [GFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) was upgraded.
I noticed that it seems now able to target sites more precisely - logging on Facebook or Twitter has recently been more difficult, whereas other sites that also require a VPN are apparently downloading faster than before.

Comment: But the comments mentions a VPN was not necessary before (see also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276372/6309, Nov 2014). What changed at the end of June 2015?

Comment: Hummm... I thought a VPN was necessary... but you may be correct, because I am through VPN most times, I might not remember clearly. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Stack Exchange itself is accessible from China, but the site is effectively crippled. The CDNs that Stack Exchange relies on are blocked, causing Stack Exchange websites to load extremely slowly, and not really work in the end. You have to wait for every CDN request to timeout for the page to finish loading. Maybe this has changed recently, and that's the reason for increased traffic from China.

Comment: /me wonders if a Chinese CDN slave is in order in any case, considering user numbers

Answer (score 8):

**THIS HAS LITTLE TO NOTHING TO DO WITH VPN ISSUES IN CHINA.**

**--- This is primarily new traffic. An increase in visitors to SOF ---**

Specifically, from China.

Look at the first image, exactly where the question mark (?) is drawn. The total traffic for that period sees an increase directly proportional to the increase in traffic from China.

If this had anything to do with Chinese users not using their VPNs, then it would not contribute to a total increase in traffic. Correspondingly, there would be a decline in traffic from the regions whence their VPNs were.

It takes a little time to grok that China is a very different kind of country, with a massively different culture to the majority of the world. The nearest to it is Russia, but they're not even close to being the same mindset.

There are equivalent, but much more specialised, sites in China for programming Q&A. Until recently most Chinese programmers I've spoken with hardly used/or considered Stack Overflow.

It's likely Stack Overflow has become more widely known, slowly, and an article or three (well placed) mentioning it been the beginning of more concerted discussion and reference to it. Hence the increase in traffic.

Look closely at the spikes in the subsequent images. They are exactly the kinds of spikes of attention and usage that come from external media and increased awareness.

The Chinese programming community is enormous.

**Stack Overflow has (for many years) been accessible from China without a VPN.**

Comment: Was there an article published on June 25th or 26th which could explain a 2 to 5 time increase in traffic for the next 2 months straight?

Comment: I don't imagine it would be one article, but a few significant and well placed articles might well do that. Especially if one of the aforementioned local community and Q&A sites closed.

Comment: Look at the nature of those thin, big spikes, they're the kind of thing you get from external media.

Comment: Your premise is flawed. If 100 users all VPN through the same IP, and then switch to all using their own IP, that is interpreted through this metric as  a 100 fold increase.

Comment: `StackOverflow has (for many years) been accessible from China without a VPN.` It's always been accessible without a VPN. Being *usable* without a VPN is an entirely different story.

Comment: Accessible? .. sort of. Not universally. A frequent support case that we field via email comes from Chinese users that can't login because they can't download resources from our CDN. While `stackoverflow.com` has been whitelisted for a while, `*.sstatic.net` as well as `*.stackexchange.com` and `*.stackauth.com` have _not_, so this could actually be a pretty big turn. At least I'm hoping :)

Comment: @TimPost, defk? You mean the firewall operates on a one-by-one whitelist instead of a one-by-one blacklist?

Comment: It has both. Depends on the size, scope and nature of the sites in question. In the case of SO, it seems to be about some of their tracking and advertising and login credential technologies being deemed to be needlessly draconian, informative and specific. The "Chinese firewall" can be best thought of as primarily designed to project Chinese people from needless monitoring and unwittingly providing too much information to others.

Comment: @Confused, Any links to official Chinese Government sites about this?