# Sporadic accessibility of Stack Overflow in China

Tags: support, bug, china

I spent the last three days in Guangzhou, China, and, being pathologically addicted to using Stack Overflow, decided to spend a portion of my evenings answering questions.  To my disappointment, the site had some accessibility problems.  Sometimes the site was fully accessible, but other times a given page either would not load at all, or would only load after many minutes.  As a control, I checked sites like Google and Facebook (which are fully blocked), and sites like Yahoo and Wikipedia (which are fully accessible, without any issues).

I can't explain this, and [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302667/whats-up-with-china) seems to say that there should be no problem with China.  One theory I had is that some of the ads on the pages might be using Google or some other blocked service, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Plenty of questions here from people who have trouble accessing SO in China, especially with CDNs.

Comment: Why is this a bug? The Great Firewall is a fact of life, and it is well known that it can result in spotty/sproradic/slow access--it's not just binary. What do you imagine could be done about this? Shall we have Joel give a buzz to Xi Jinping? More importantly, why are you hunched over your laptop in your hotel room in China instead of going out to see some pandas or something?

Answer (score 8):

We really can't control it, or other circumstances where equipment deliberately interferes with pages loading properly. For performance issues, a number of things are served from a content delivery network and China sporadically blocks access to these.

To my knowledge, this has never broken anyone's ability to read a question and answer that turned up in a search - which is good; folks facing this can still find answers to their questions.

However, when stuff deliberately keeps certain things from loading, we can't possibly guarantee the experience that someone would have, and we can't really optimize for selectively switching to / from content delivery networks based on a vague idea of hosts that *might* have difficulty reaching the CDNs.

A solution could be implemented client-side, but that would require mirroring everything on our CDN as well as Google's on a host that's known to be available there then testing for those elements and loading from a fallback if they're not found - but what happens if that mirror suddenly falls out of favor with the GFOC?

As much as I hate it, we can't optimize for situations similar to folks deliberately pulling the ethernet cable out of their computers at various stages of a page trying to load (which is, effectively, what it looks like from a software perspective).

Comment: Hi Tim, I like your answer and your first name, and I will mark correct unless some other SO employee chooses to post.  I was weirded out by SO pages sometimes partially loading, and you've explained why this is happening.

Comment: The GFOC actually has a bug tracker where you can appeal a block believe it or not, and folks have used that to try and get our external resources whitelisted. The fact that we render pretty well even with missing elements might be why we're still dealing with it, as someone goes and checks and says "this looks fine!" - that would be a little ironic if true, just a guess at this point though.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't help that [some people are deliberately trying to get SO blocked in China](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298950/660921).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, You can't "deliberately" get something blocked without the **consent** of the blocker.