# Ask for a solution to avoid SE being blocked in China

Tags: support, china

Sorry to bringup this topic again. I read these links but they did not answer my question.
[Is Stack Overflow accessible in China?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267715/is-stack-overflow-accessible-in-china)
[What's up with China?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302667/whats-up-with-china)

It seems to me certain JavaScripts used by Stack Exchange are somehow on the blacklist of our government media control. (I say this because I saw warnings from my Chrome browser) The results is (as of today), SE sites load very slowly, even though they will eventually show up. But they are having great difficulties. The contents looks okay, it is just the loading process is unbearable.

Besides logging-in is a pain too.

Anyone know what these JavaScripts might be? And anyway to remove/replace those JavaScripts? I'll be happy to assist. Please correct me if I was wrong. Thanks

[image: screenshot of the warning message]

Comment: ajax.googleapis.com is the external source. Open the network tab and look at the times. You can probably get info on Super User about how to save the required scripts and host them on your own machine. This isn't much of a Meta Stack Overflow question.

Comment: related on MSE: [Add a fallback for jQuery in case it fails to load from Google's CDN](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133786/134300)

Comment: Userscript to switch to an alternative CDN or a VPN proxy?

Comment: SE and SO are not banned. But all google websites are banned. So all the website that use googleapis.com are very slow to open. Very painful.

Answer (score -2):

when I access the website, I was identified as a robot since of your reason.So I use shadow-socks as proxy, and everything is ok now.