# New Social Issue Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

In the discussion about the [Take a Stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) post it was [suggested by Sun Qingyao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342553/773263) that Stack Overflow could create a new tag for social justice related issues:

> I'm also glad to see a fifth tag (preferably hidden from ordinary
>   users) apart from discussion, support, feature-request and bug, say
>   special, which is dedicated to hold such special questions.

Given the huge interest in this post/topic should Stack Overflow consider creating a new tag for social justice issues which effect developers?

Comment: Oh Lord please no. -----

Comment: I briefly thought of adding a [politics] tag so people could add that tag to their tag ignore list, but on the other hand, we (ideally) shouldn't need that tag

Comment: No, instead we should prevent questions that would use this tag from being posted and existing in the first place.

Answer (score 68):

Please no.

It's one thing when SO, Inc./Joel decides to take a position on a political issue, and do so on Meta. Some people don't like it, others do, but either way it clearly is a special case.

It's another thing entirely to create a tag that will encourage *everyone else* to chime in.

There's a million places where social discourse can be had. Twitter, for example, can be a good place for finding intelligent voices with less trolling than in other places (plus it's easy to filter out everything except those you choose to follow.) There's other places, too.

Comment: *"Twitter...can be a good place for finding intelligent voices"* Your experience is rather different than mine.

Comment: @CodyGray you are obviously interacting with wrong people on Twitter ;-)

Comment: *"with less trolling than in other places"* - wow, where else are you hanging out?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe lol. Perhaps a more accurate way to put it is that on Twitter it's easier to filter/block out the trolls.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea either, but it could be a moderator-only tag.

Answer (score 26):

I hope this meta post was a one off because of a particularly egregious order.

I further hope that this doesn't mark a trend where meta.SO is regularly used to rally support for the american left, since that'd annoy loads of international viewers (we can't do anything, it's not our country, not our representatives).

Since I hope and think this post should remain unique in its scope and no further ones like it should follow, I don't think a tag would be appropriate.

Comment: Does "american left" mean the USA Democratic party? If yes, it's out of place here. It looks like you are trying to say "Don't support the Democrats" while you are probably trying to say "Don't go off-topic".

Comment: @anatolyg Saying it because Joel is left on the spectrum and this is his site. Left and right are independant of Dem or Gop in this case.

Answer (score 14):

I do not think this tag is necessary. Social issues are an exception, not the norm. They don't normally have a place on SO.

It is inevitable that some issues will affect us as developers; like SOPA or software patenting.

But making a separate tag for this, suggests that these things are normal and on-topic. It would invite people to post such questions for many things that they believe need our attention.

So, I'm saying **don't** make a tag for social issues. Leave them under [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). These questions really are discussion items, that happen to affect the world beyond Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -63):

**Yes**, the world is coming into the dark times.

I believe that going forward Trump will make many more controversial decisions. It's important that the tech community has a tag dedicated to denouncing future steps he may take.

This freeze on green cards from 7 countries is only the beginning. **Next month Trump will build the wall.**

If anything there is a need for such posts at an ever increasing frequency.

Comment: A lot of people will agree with you, especially here. But there is a time and a place - and this isn't the place.