# Is it OK for businesses to use Stack Overflow as their official support-forum?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

I was interested in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267676/heima588-com-looks-exactly-the-same-as-stack-overflow-what-is-the-link-between/267826#267826), and light-heartedly searched Google for other websites that duplicate/copy Stack Overflow, and I came across [this](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/support-forum).

SagePay seems to be using Stack Overflow as their *'official support forums'* (to quote), and are redirecting all their customers wishing to use a support-forum to Stack Overflow, under the SagePay tag.

Is this type of behaviour allowed, especially since there's probably no formal agreement involved between such businesses and Stack Overflow?

And another thing, the SagePay page mentions this:

> Our forum community

Do they have the authority to 'claim ownership' of the users on Stack Overflow using the SagePay tag?
I don't think so somehow!

Examples of other businesses parlicipating in such behaviour:

- [Socrata](https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/202951648-Technical-question-Post-it-on-StackOverflow-)
- [OpenXAVA (they even had the cheek to complain about the moderators on here!)](http://openxava.org/blog/moving-support-to-stackoverflow)
- [Eventbrite](http://developer.eventbrite.com/discussion/)

..and that's just the [first page](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=Stack%20Overflow%20is%20a%20question%20and%20answer%20site%20for%20professional%20and%20enthusiast%20programmers&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&hl=en&q=Support%20forum%20on%20Stack%20Overflow) of a Google Search!

Comment: Related: [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253394).  See also [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) and [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3966/102937)

Comment: @Will Exactly. It's not particularly fair to the owners of Stack Overflow since they have to pay for the server and hosting costs that the business would otherwise be paying if the forums were hosted on their own servers.

In addition, please mind your language.

Comment: Clicking view all on the eventbrite page brings you back to SO showing all 171 questions tagged as eventbright.  I guess they consider all 171 posts 'open support tickets' for themselves?

Comment: If you want to stop it, the best thing to do is monitor those tags and close everything that isn't a good question faster than they can answer them.  Its doubtful their people are high rep users capable of stopping them. Make the experience as bad as possible and they'll stop, because their users will complain.  Keep the good questions open though.

Answer (score 13):

In general, the problem with "We have moved our support forum to Stack Overflow" pages is that

1. We're not actually a forum, and we don't work the same way as forums
2. We don't field Customer Support questions, and
3. You still have to ask questions that are on-topic for the Stack Overflow community.

Note that:

1. Socrata is very specific about how Stack Overflow should be properly used.
2. OpenXava got disillusioned and quit Stack Overflow, returning to their regular forums.
3. Eventbrite's page is abysmal.  It just links to the Stack Overflow Ask page.  Maybe they never had their own support.

SagePay is somewhere in-between.  They make it clear that Stack Overflow is a separate site, but don't really explain how it works.

Comment: True. It also damages the companies' reputation badly if they're sending customers to Stack Overflow (aka, their [un]official support [non]forum), since off-topic questions can and WILL be closed. This was experienced by OpenXava since they complained about moderators closing questions related to OpenXava since many were off-topic.

Comment: So what does SO do about abysmal pages like Eventbrite?

Comment: @gitsitgo They get an email from [Tim Post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product/253852#253852)