# Spotify is suggesting to use Stack Overflow for customer support

Tags: support, outsourcing

[The Tweet in question](https://twitter.com/SpotifyCares/status/880963879358132224)

> “I’d love to talk to some developers about it”. - Jay Hankins

> “Thanks for the heads-up. You can ask our dev
> team at http://spoti.fi/1lpzKfR for more info. They'll be able to help out /MT” - SpotifyCares

[image]

As far as I know this isn't something Stack Overflow recommends. Maybe someone from Stack Overflow can reach out to them to explain that.

References:

- [Is it OK for businesses to use Stack Overflow as their official support-forum?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267828/is-it-ok-for-businesses-to-use-stack-overflow-as-their-official-support-forum)
- [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: Does this mean I can get free music? /s

Comment: I think the person replying via the Spotify Twitter probably confused *"talk to some developers"* with *"Spotify software development resource"*.

Comment: That feeling when you remember you cant downvote tweets.

Comment: This issue wasn't a code/dev problem though. It's a customer care type issue.

Comment: _you can ask our dev team_ they didn't pay a single penny to SO.

Comment: What?! You mean someone is saying *wrong things* on Twitter? Stop the presses! This must be the first time this has ever happened.

Comment: More interessting are the 4 close votes, that this question is not about Stack Overflow...

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt just noticed that, not really sure where this should be posted according to those who have voted to close since this is definitely about Stack overflow. :\

Comment: It is not about Stack Overflow. It's about Twitter and Spotify. There is nothing that the community can do about this except troll this person on Twitter.

Comment: Thankfully the person who asked the question [noted that this isn't what SO is for](https://twitter.com/jay_hankins/status/880981435988848640).  Maybe someone with SO can gently suggest they try [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spotify) instead?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spotify/topusers)

Comment: @Ihazkode `7
Last 7 Days
85.7% unanswered
50
Last 30 Days
80% unanswered
2,120
All Time
37.5% unanswered
` :|

Comment: It's OK, Pekka is on the job ;)

Comment: Does stackexchange make money with this approach ?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I wish Pekka's reply ("The person who wrote this tweet is not really familiar with Stack Overflow, are they?") wasn't as snarky. Most support people aren't familiar with Stack Overflow, because support people aren't programmers, and non-programmers are not familiar with Stack Overflow. Instead, a factual reply about why this is the wrong approach would have been better.

Comment: @Andrew that's actually a fair point. I'll write a better tweet.

Comment: Done: https://twitter.com/Pekkanikolaus/status/881771381750456321

Comment: @Andrew thanks for pointing it out. Heat of the moment, and all that.

Comment: It was a strange to finally see Pekka's face in another light (or lack thereof). It has... _features_! :D

Comment: @xDaizu Pekka's reaction: 웃