# Sagepay seems to be using Stack Overflow for all support

Tags: support, outsourcing

Looks like [Sagepay is using Stack Overflow as their "support forum"](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/support-forum). They make no attempt to indicate that Stack Overflow is only for programming assistance or that there are guidelines for its use.

I learned of this because [a user came to Stack Overflow asking if Sagepay offers a particular payment service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47268826/250259). Looks like we may need to reach out to them to let them know improvement is desired?

Comment: The page mentions that SO is for programmers, and that page also has a link to a forum that they run for general support questions, an FAQ page, as well as a phone number, email, and twitter link.  I'm not so sure the company is the one at fault here.  The user just choose the wrong support option for the type of question they had.

Comment: The page even has a link to a new question with sagepay tag pre-populated.

Comment: I've seen worse examples but maybe they can add a bit more guidance up front

Comment: It's also worth noting that not only does that page have links for non-developer resources, but in order to get to that page from the general support page they needed to click on the "developers" support option, rather than the "business" support option, indicating that the nature of the support is programming related.  Honestly the company did a pretty good job here.

Comment: Not the first time SagePay has come up: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267828/is-it-ok-for-businesses-to-use-stack-overflow-as-their-official-support-forum

Comment: They have a "How does Stack Overflow work" link.  That this SO page doesn't actually say anything about what kind of questions are on topic is, well, you know.   Notifying an employee that answers SO questions tends to work, done.

Comment: We'll get in touch with them; thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Servy I think they're at least partly to blame. A link titled _Sage Pay forum_  with subtitle _Speak with our online community of developers_ also refers to the page referring to Stack Overflow. Bad style to say the least. I don't see a general forum on that site.

Comment: What's definitely way off is "[...]Stack Overflow is a great place to [...] share comments with fellow Sage Pay customers". No, it isn't!!

Answer (score 9):

Well... I sent this to support@sagepay.com, which was the only email address I could find that didn't bounce:

> Hello,
>
> Your website currently sends customers to our website (Stack Overflow) via this support page: https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/support-forum
>
> However, Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for programming questions - which is to say, anything that isn't a programming question or answer will not be greeted with very much enthusiasm by the other users of the site. This has already caused some amount of disappointment on behalf of your customers who attempted to ask questions regarding your service offerings that I'm sure you would've preferred were directed to your sales staff.
>
> To be clear, it is completely fine to send software developers looking to ask questions about software development to Stack Overflow, even questions about software development using the SagePay APIs. However, you should direct those with other sorts of questions to a different venue.
>
> This is the current introduction from the page I linked to above:
>
> Our community on Stack Overflow is a great place to post questions and share comments with fellow Sage Pay customers, partners and developers. Look out for the 'Sage Pay' tag.
>
> I recommend something more specific, such as:
>
> "Our community on Stack Overflow is a great place to ask questions and share answers about integrating software with the Sage Pay API. Check out the Sage Pay tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sagepay" ... For questions on other topics, see: https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support"
>
> Please also peruse this guide to product support on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support
>
> Best regards,
>   Josh Heyer
>   Community Manager
>   Stack Exchange

I haven't received a reply yet. If I ever do, I'll update this post.