# What about Microsoft Office Store support?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

I just stumbled on the [office-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-store) tag and looked over some of the questions. Most of them seem to revolve around the theme of "why was my app rejected" or be specific questions targeting the Office Store support. Since there is also a user called "Office Store Developer Comms" I get the impression that somehow developers are encouraged to post their support-request on SO without proper guidance what might be on topic or not. With a quick search I did not find anything related on the Microsoft sites, so I thought to ask whether somone knows how this stuff turns up here and if there should something be done.

Comment: Also: [Is it OK for businesses to use Stack Overflow as their official support forum?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267828) | [Are developer centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: I don't see them advertising SO support for [office-store] anywhere obvious.  Programmers on the MSFT stack just automatically assume they'll find support at SO, only small companies need to point it out.

Comment: The excerpt needs some attention: *questions about how the Store works, including how to publish, pass validation, and acquire add-ins* not sure if all those topic are programming related

Comment: You could post a burninate request for this tag. I believe the topics rene referred to are all off-topic (either Super User, customer support or blatantly off-topic), and I can't think of logical on-topic use for the tag.

Comment: @HansPassant it seems they actually do advertise it somwhere, but you can't find it on the website - see this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057604/some-pop-ups-when-clicked-on-links-in-owa-are-blocked-by-certain-browsers-is#comment83281257_48057604