# Burninate office-store tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, outsourcing

[Previous discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359685/what-about-microsoft-office-store-support)

In that discussion, commenters weren't sure whether Microsoft was actually inviting people to post explicitly off-topic question on this tag. Microsoft [does](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store) invite people to ask off-topic questions on SO here:

> If you have general questions about policies, processes, or validation
>   requirements, you can engage with the AppSource Validation Team via
>   Stack Overflow. Tag your question with "Office-Store".

Looking at what happened to recent questions, Microsoft is also failing to answer questions tagged [office-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-store).

Comment: SOunds good to me.

Comment: Not sure that *some* people misusing a tag means the tag needs to be burninated. Is the tag on-topic for SO? If it is, then it should remain. Just needs to be policed...same as any other tag.

Comment: Might be worth having someone reach out to Microsoft about their wording. The tag's usage guidelines already state that T&C and customer service questions are off topic.

Comment: Considering that all of Microsoft's Documentation is on GitHub now, a Feedback Item on the page would seem appropriate. SO isn't the place for the questions Microsoft is saying should be asked. Not sure what community would be, if any, but certainly not here.

Comment: Note that I edited the tag guidelines to add text about the question needing to be about programming. If anyone actually reads that, they'll know they shouldn't be asking policy questions. Not much more *we* can do.

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not but we were part of a post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510513/add-in-suddenly-missing-from-office-add-in-store-on-mac-word). We paid the $500 dollars for Microsoft priority support and they told us to post to SO to get support. Even if you burninate the tag Microsoft will still direct users and not programmers to ask off-topic questions here. They also seem to ignore any requests from SO members to stop using SO in this manner.

Comment: Well, since the MS support people do not seem to be interested in any form of dialogue, all we could do is give this tag extra scrutiny and aggressively close and downvote OT-questions and answers. With a bit of luck it might even result in the account getting answer-banned ;)